# postgresql - join between two large tables takes very long

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I do have two rather large tables and I need to do a date range join between those. Unfortunately the query takes over 12 hours. I am using postgresql 10.5 running in docker with max. 5GB of ram and up to 12 CPU cores available.

Basically in the left table I do have an Equipment ID and a list of date ranges (from = Timestamp, to = ValidUntil). I then want to join the right table, which has measurements (sensor data) for all of the equipments, so that I only get the sensor data that lies within one of the date ranges (from the left table). Query:

```
select
    A.*,
    B."Timestamp" as "PressureTimestamp",
    B."PropertyValue" as "Pressure"
from A
inner join B
    on  B."EquipmentId" =  A."EquipmentId"
    and B."Timestamp"   >= A."Timestamp"
    and B."Timestamp"   <  A."ValidUntil"
```

This query unfortunately is only utilizing one core, which might be the reason that it is running that slow. Is there a way to rewrite the query so it can be parallelized?

**Indexes:**

```
create index if not exists A_eq_timestamp_validUntil on public.A using btree ("EquipmentId", "Timestamp", "ValidUntil");
create index if not exists B_eq_timestamp on public.B using btree ("EquipmentId", "Timestamp");
```

**Tables:**

```
-- contains 332,000 rows
CREATE TABLE A (
    "EquipmentId" bigint,
    "Timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
    "ValidUntil" timestamp without time zone
)
WITH ( OIDS = FALSE )

-- contains 70,000,000 rows
CREATE TABLE B
(
    "EquipmentId" bigint,
    "Timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
    "PropertyValue" double precision
)
WITH ( OIDS = FALSE )
```

**Execution plan (explain ... output):**

```
Nested Loop  (cost=176853.59..59023908.95 rows=941684055 width=48)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on v2_pressure p  (cost=176853.16..805789.35 rows=9448335 width=24)
        Recheck Cond: ("EquipmentId" = 2956235)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on v2_pressure_eq  (cost=0.00..174491.08 rows=9448335 width=0)
              Index Cond: ("EquipmentId" = 2956235)"
  ->  Index Scan using v2_prs_eq_timestamp_validuntil on v2_prs prs  (cost=0.42..5.16 rows=100 width=32)
        Index Cond: (("EquipmentId" = 2956235) AND (p."Timestamp" >= "Timestamp") AND (p."Timestamp" < "ValidUntil"))
```

**Update 1:**
Fixed the indexes, according to comments, which improved performance a lot

Comment: you don't seem to have any indexes on those tables. Try one on `b("Timestsamp")` and one on `a("Timestamp", "ValidUntil")`

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it

Comment: Postgres will in general only use one index.  You have defined three separate indices, on three different columns.  You probably want to try a _composite_ index involving some or all of the columns involved in the join.

Comment: using indexes improves the situation as it seems (test still running) but it still is only using 1 core. Is there a way to write the query in a way so pgsql can execute the query in parallel?

Comment: You can try to explicitly hash join, maybe that helps with the Heap scan in the execution plan.

Comment: Do these tables have Primary Keys? And, If there is a 1:N relationship between them, there could even be a Foreign Key ...

Comment: @wildplasser Relationship is 1:n. There is no primary key. Records can be uniquely identified via `("EquipmentId, "Timestamp")` in both tables. There is an index however on the mentioned fields for both tables.

Comment: `Records can be uniquely identified via ("EquipmentId, "Timestamp") in both tables. ` ... which implies that this is the PK in *both tables* .

Comment: @wildplasser As windows in table A do not overlap they can be unique identified using (Equipment, Timestamp). But we are not joining on those those key fields only but on a range. Hence the join results in 1:n. Multiple records in table B belong to one record (which defines a time range) in A.

Comment: @wildplasser IMHO your comment is not useful. It is not possible to define a foreign key relationship. Also there is no speed improvement by adding primary keys over just using indexes. Also it is not necessary to maintain integrity (e.g. by using FK) in my use case. This only about optimizing performance of the join - nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Index correction is the first resort to fix slowness but it will only help to some extent. Given that your tables are big I would recommend to try Postgres [Partition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html) . It has some inbuilt support from postgres.

But you need to have some filter/partition criteria. I don't see any where clause in your query so can't suggest. May be you can try equipmentId. This can also help in achieving parallelism.

Comment: I have tried using the EquipmentId as partition key (resulting in 13 partitions). However checking the exection plan postgres basically collected the data from all partitions and then joined them all together against the other table (which I did not partion). Maybe I will try again using partioned tables for A and B using the same partition key.
Problem also was that I was no longer able to create indexes e.g. on the Timestamps.

Comment: That's the side-effect of partition. partition criteria has to be part of your where clause e.g with 'IN' and there should be an index on it then only it will scan a particular partition not all of them. That's why it is important to choose partition criteria wisely depending on your application.  You should be able to create indexes on partition table. I would suggest to read more and play around with it as it is not straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- \i tmp.sql

CREATE TABLE A
        ( equipmentid bigint NOT NULL
        , ztimestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
        , validuntil timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY (equipmentid,ztimestamp)
        , UNIQUE (equipmentid,validuntil) -- mustbeunique, since the intervals dont overlap
        ) ;

-- contains 70,000,000 rows
CREATE TABLE B
        ( equipmentid bigint NOT NULL
        , ztimestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
        , propertyvalue double precision
        , PRIMARY KEY (equipmentid,ztimestamp)
        ) ;

INSERT INTO B(equipmentid,ztimestamp,propertyvalue)
SELECT i,t, random()
FROM generate_series(1,1000) i
CROSS JOIN generate_series('2018-09-01','2018-09-30','1day'::interval) t
        ;


INSERT INTO A(equipmentid,ztimestamp,validuntil)
SELECT equipmentid,ztimestamp, ztimestamp+ '7 days'::interval
FROM B
WHERE date_part('dow', ztimestamp) =0
        ;

ANALYZE A;
ANALYZE B;

EXPLAIN
SELECT
    A.*,
    B.ztimestamp AS pressuretimestamp,
    B.propertyvalue AS pressure
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
    ON  B.equipmentid =  A.equipmentid
    AND B.ztimestamp   >= A.ztimestamp
    AND B.ztimestamp   <  A.validuntil
    WHERE A.equipmentid=333 -- I added this, the plan in the question also has a r estriction on Id
        ;
```

---

And the resulting plan:

---

```
SET
ANALYZE
ANALYZE
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.34..21.26 rows=17 width=40)
   ->  Index Scan using a_equipmentid_validuntil_key on a  (cost=0.17..4.34 rows=5 width=24)
         Index Cond: (equipmentid = 333)
   ->  Index Scan using b_pkey on b  (cost=0.17..3.37 rows=3 width=24)
         Index Cond: ((equipmentid = 333) AND (ztimestamp >= a.ztimestamp) AND (ztimestamp < a.validuntil))
(5 rowSET
```

---

That is with my current setting of `random_page_cost=1.1;`

After setting it to 4.0, I get the same plan as the OP:

---

```
SET
                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=35.13..54561.69 rows=1416136 width=40) (actual time=1.391..1862.275 rows=225540 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on aa2  (cost=34.71..223.52 rows=1345 width=24) (actual time=1.173..5.223 rows=1345 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (equipmentid = 5)
         Heap Blocks: exact=9
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on aa2_equipmentid_validuntil_key  (cost=0.00..34.38 rows=1345 width=0) (actual time=1.047..1.048 rows=1345 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (equipmentid = 5)
   ->  Index Scan using bb2_pkey on bb2  (cost=0.42..29.87 rows=1053 width=24) (actual time=0.109..0.757 rows=168 loops=1345)
         Index Cond: ((equipmentid = 5) AND (ztimestamp >= aa2.ztimestamp) AND (ztimestamp < aa2.validuntil))
 Planning Time: 3.167 ms
 Execution Time: 2168.967 ms
(10 rows)
```

Comment: I have copied your create table statements, added my index statements from the original question and then copied my actual data into the tables. My execution plan, however, looks different from yours: https://pastebin.com/vTPSkiNi

Comment: Note on the table names: v2_test_prs = A & v2_test_pressure = B

Comment: 1) the rowcount estimates seem rather high, did you (after the inserts) run analyse on the tables? 2) Why did you add extra indexes?  The PK+UNIQUE will give sufficient indexing power. 3) is the distitribution of IDs very skew ? Is the cardinality of IDs low ? (inprobable, since it is a bigint)

Comment: yes I did run "analyze" on both tables. Different equipments have varying number of entries in both tables: https://imgur.com/a/UylqcFC . I am also using the join primarily to filter entries from B. I'd expect that per entry in A I have 30-45 matching entries in table B. The 2 additional indexes should not hurt, right (expect storage is increased) ? Also it seems that pg is actually using them.

Comment: I get the same plan as yours when I `SET random_page_cost=4;` Wich is the default. Try setting it lower,  (to ~1.2)